# Why is Homebrew installed in /opt/homebrew on Apple Silicon Macs?

Tags: homebrew, apple-silicon

The Homebrew [installation](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) page says:

> This script installs Homebrew to its preferred prefix (/usr/local for
> macOS Intel, /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon and
> /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew for Linux) so that you don’t need sudo when
> you brew install. It is a careful script; it can be run even if you
> have stuff installed in the preferred prefix already. It tells you
> exactly what it will do before it does it too. You have to confirm
> everything it will do before it starts.

Why does Homebrew choose `/opt/homebrew` as the installation prefix for Apple Silicon Macs instead of `/usr/local` like it does for Intel Macs?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would highly recommend checking out the original Homebrew discussion [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/9177). I'll summarise a few points from it below.

The default prefix before Apple Silicon (`/usr/local`) was chosen for a few reasons:

- It's already in PATH. This means that tools installed with homebrew can be accessed without any need to change anything.
- Quite a few build systems already look in `/usr/local`, so libraries installed with homebrew can be used by non-homebrew tools.

The Apple Silicon transition came with a change in the default Homebrew prefix. Some of the reasons for this included:

- `/usr/local` is also used by other tools, not just Homebrew. This can lead to potential conflicts.
- Installations in `/opt/homebrew` for Apple Silicon and `/usr/local` for Rosetta 2 can coexist.
- Homebrew tools might not always want to be used by default. A different prefix would make this easier.

There was also an interesting [article](https://applehelpwriter.com/2018/03/21/how-homebrew-invites-users-to-get-pwned/) a while back about some of the potential security risks with `/usr/local` that you might find interesting.

Other macOS package managers were already using different prefixes (MacPorts with `/opt/local` and Fink with `/opt/sw`). MacPorts listed some reasons why they don't use `/usr/local` [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#defaultprefix), and Fink has [here](https://www.finkproject.org/faq/general.php?phpLang=en#usr-local).

Just to note, [although not recommended](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#why-should-i-install-homebrew-in-the-default-location),  Homebrew can technically be installed anywhere. However, pre-built bottles/binaries are only available on the default prefix.

Comment: I like the first comment in each of  the Homebrew reasons - they rather cancel out.

Comment: Can you force the pre-built bottles/binaries to be installed into a custom prefix as well?

Comment: No, not really. Often, the prefix might be hardcoded into compiled files during build time. There's no easy way of changing this short of building locally in the custom prefix.

Comment: Related entry from the FAQ: "[**Why is the default installation prefix /opt/homebrew on Apple Silicon?**](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-is-the-default-installation-prefix-opthomebrew-on-apple-silicon) The prefix `/opt/homebrew` was chosen to allow installations in `/opt/homebrew` for Apple Silicon and `/usr/local` for Rosetta 2 to coexist and use bottles."

Comment: I'm actually happier that they made this change. I've been resisting using Homebrew precisely because I have tons of random stuff under `/usr/local` (it's the default for a lot of `make install` software and some software expects to be installed there).

Answer (score 10):

From the Homebrew [FAQ](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-is-the-default-installation-prefix-opthomebrew-on-apple-silicon) :

> The prefix /opt/homebrew was chosen to allow installations in /opt/homebrew for Apple Silicon and /usr/local for Rosetta 2 to coexist and use bottles.

This allows the installation and execution of two Homebrew versions simultaneously on Apple Silicon, one for ARM and one for Intel under Rosetta. See further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951024/how-can-i-run-two-isolated-installations-of-homebrew)