# Problems with Terminal commands in macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, terminal, ventura

Since I upgraded my M1 MacBook Pro to MacOS Ventura 13.0, the Terminal app does not work correctly.

When I type, for example, `rm -rf ...`, it gets killed as shown in the screenshot below. I get this response for a lot of other commands in Terminal. In addition, I now get Unexpected Error when I try to build an application in Xcode. Same problems appear with either ZSH or Bash.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is more readable and convenient for others if you paste the text form of commands and outputs from Terminal to your questions rather than the screenshots.

Comment: Are these the standard built-in command-line tools, or are you using something nonstandard like homebrew? Does [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/441000/most-homebrew-installed-commands-outputs-zsh-killed) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303644/apple-m1-with-macos-big-sur-11-2-1-install-soft-faild-with-killed-error) help?

Comment: MBP-von-Daniel:~ danielehrhardt$ ls
Killed: 9

I try to use mkdir, ls, rm

Comment: Can you try `bash` and then the commands? Maybe this is some misconfiguration in your zshrc files?

Comment: bash
Killed: 9

also happening with bash

Comment: It does also happen with a new created user.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253676819

Comment: i will reinstall my mac

Comment: What is that ```Kill | system node | time``` in the lower right of the screen?

Comment: Make sure you have "Terminal" listed in the "Security > Full Disk Access" system setting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At first i thought that chmod fixed the Issue but then i opned iTerm with ZSH and had the same killed Issue again. I ended up also deleting all content from `/usr/local/bin` and changed my Path Variable to use the /bin folder.

```
/bin/chmod 755 /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: How did that directory get corrupted?

Comment: macOS Ventura update

Comment: Which permissions did the directory have before the chmod?

Comment: Same problem but I would advise care, only delete files that are already present in /bin, not everything !

Comment: I have the same issue. I even tried reinstalling ventura again.
What do you suggest? Uninstall commandlineTools or delete usr/local/bin contents'; the latter seems little dangerous. @DanielEhrhardt

Comment: Save the folder, delete the files and check if it works